# $.get converts numbers to strings

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Am using $.get to send some values when decoding them in php they are all converted to strings even though they are numbers.

CODE:

```
var id_from = 19;
var id_to = 19;
$.get("save.php",{id_from:id_from,id_to:id_to }, function(){

 console.log(result)
 });
```

On the save.php

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET)
?>
```

Am getting

```
array(2) {
  ["id_from"]=>
 string(1) "1"
 ["id_to"]=>
 string(1) "4"
}
```

How can i get the values as integers  since they are output as strings

Comment: where to convert?? `javascript` or `PHP`??

Comment: you can always typecast it back to `int` from php

Comment: That really shouldn't be a big issues, since php is loosely typed and will understand at once it's dealing with numbers. And by the way, you can alwasy cast them to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this:**

> **PHP**

By typecasting you can do this.

```
$value = "4";

$val = (int) $value;

echo var_dump($value); //string(1) "4"
echo var_dump($val); // int(4)
```

Comment: Yeahh so it was just typecasting.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function to convert it to int

```
<?php
echo intval($_GET['id_from'])."|".$_GET['id_from'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [type cast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) in PHP Server side.

```
 $id_from = (int) $_GET['id_from']
```